# Geometry problem involving similar triangles inscribed in two intersecting circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

[image]Assume that $ΔABC\sim ΔAB_1C_1$ (where the corners are ordered in that way, i.e. direct similarity). Show that the intersection $M≠A$ between the circles around the two triangles coincides with the intersection between $BB_1$ and $CC_1$

There is a lot of properties for triangles inscribed in circles, some of them are listed [here](http://www.timdevereux.co.uk/maths/geompages/8theorem.php).What i struggle to see is how to use this when considering two different circles.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $M$ be the intersection point of $BB_1$ and $CC_1$.

Since the triangles $ABC$ and $AB_1C_1$ are similar we have:
$$
\angle BAB_1=\angle BAC_1-\angle C_1AB_1
=\angle CAC_1+\underbrace{\angle CAB-\angle C_1AB_1}_{=0}=\angle CAC_1.
$$

Since further:
$$
\frac{AB}{AB_1}=\frac{AC}{AC_1}
$$
we can conclude:
$$
\begin{align}
\triangle CAC_1\sim \triangle BAB_1\implies\quad&\\
\\
1.\quad \angle ABB_1=\angle ACC_1&\implies \angle ABM=\angle ACM\\
&\implies AMBC\text{ cyclic }\implies M\in \bigcirc ABC;\\
\\
2.\quad \angle AB_1B=\angle AC_1C&\implies \angle AB_1M=\angle AC_1M\\
&\implies AMB_1C_1\text{ cyclic }\implies M\in \bigcirc AB_1C_1.\\
\end{align}
$$

In the above proof it was assumed that the point pairs $B,C$ and $B_1,C_1$ are in the different half-planes created by the line $AM$. The same argument can be however applied with minor changes for all possible arrangements:
$$(BC|B_1C_1),(BCB_1|C_1),(BCB_1C_1|),(BB_1|CC_1).$$

The second arrangement as an example is shown in the next figure:

[image]